# SPContext.Current is null in a web service under a sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, web-services

I'm exposing a web service in a SharePoint site e.g. http://server/_vti_bin/subdir/mywebservice.asmx.

In the web service method, `SPContext.Current` appears to be null.

(Interestingly, I'm looking at an example in Chapter 5 of [Inside Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623201) and they use `SPContext.Current` inside a web service!)

Any idea what am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you supply some more info and perhaps code samples?

Which specific object in SPContext.Current is null? 

How do you obtain credentials for the web service?

what authentication are you using?

Comment: +hosting IIS site is Windows authN. (How can this be related to SPContext.Current being null?)

Answer (score 2):

The only times when I saw a SPContext.Current = null was when the webservice was called at a virtual location that didn't exist (i.e. an URL that was only half correct).

In your problem specification, you mention "_vti_bin/subdir". I have not seen this subdir construct in a WebService hosted within SharePoint yet (disclaimer: my knowledge is limited to 2 or 3 working implementations of a custom webservices within SharePoint)

Normally, you'd

- Put the asmx straight into the ISAPI folder of the 12 hive. This will map onto _vti_bin.

  Put the assembly, if any, in the GAC (or in the website bin, but I'd suggest using the GAC until you get the basics up and running)

  Do stuff for discovery if you really need to, but for testing this shouldn't be necessary

It might not be related at all, but I'd still try to get things working from the _vti_bin first, *then* try and mess with subfolders. SharePoint's url virtualization can be painful.

Comment: Will give a try... as you mention, everything is hosted under ISAPI dir, code lives in a GAC'ed dll, etc. Web service actually works. Thanks.

Comment: Note: you also get SPContext.Current = null if code is called within service such as OWSTIMER (timer job).

Comment: I found a similar thing. I called the svc with the wrong url (to a deleted spsite), and the SPContext came up null.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your subdirectory is set up as a web application and is therefore operating in a different context?

Comment: http: //server is a valid web application.

Comment: The question really was if "subdir" is also an application, which would supercede the parent directory's application and provide a different context in which SP is not running.  You could determine this by inspecting the properties of "System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment" in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the webservice? Is this an ajax call from javascript/jquery? If yes, have you added the ScriptService attribute on the webservice class?

```
[System.Web.Scripts.Services.ScriptService]
public class SimpleWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes it is, and yes, I added the ScriptService attrib, but I'm not sure how that can be related in any case. Thanks.